# EE2.x Module development reference images in css and views

Tags: add-on-development, module, stylesheets

I'm building a a module and I am having trouble trying to load images for my css styles and views..

is there a way to do this?

file stucture:
third_party:

- module

  - javascript
  - css
  - views

I have tried '../images/file.png' but no go as obviously the path is incorrect on page render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `themes` folder to use assets like images. So use a file structure like this:

```
/system/expressionengine/system/third_party/my_addon/[your-addon-files]
/system/expressionengine/system/third_party/my_addon/views/[your-addon-view-files]
/themes/third_party/my_addon/css/[css-files]
/themes/third_party/my_addon/images/[your-images]
/themes/third_party/my_addon/javascript/[your-js]
```

Then you can use `../images/my-image.png` in your css files.

Use `ee()->cp->add_to_head()` to add the CSS to the CP's head-element.

Use `ee()->cp->add_to_foot()` to add any JS to the footer of the CP.

See also:

- http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/cp.html (for CP stuff)
- http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/constants.html (for getting the paths to the themes folder)

Comment: i was afraid that would be the answer.. will have to create an installer for the module then.. oh well.

Comment: also you can use: ```ee()->cp->load_package_css('main');``` and ```ee()->cp->load_package_js('jquery-1.10.1.min');``` to load css/js into the cp